# SQL case statement with case when

Tags: sql, case-when

I have a question about SQL case statement. I have a table where 1 account can have multiple web ids(users coming from website) and app id (users coming from app). the account id is unique. I want to identify accounts based on webuser and app users. The case statement written is as follows
`(CASE WHEN (webid IS NULL AND appid is not null ) THEN 'App user' WHEN (appid IS NULL and webid is not null ) THEN 'Web user' ELSE 'Web and App user' END)` 
However the categorisation is not working correctly as it is categorsing 1 account as web user or app user as well as Web and App user. How can I fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: case *expression* , not statement.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to take the `account_id` into account as well:

```
(CASE WHEN AccountId IS NULL THEN NULL
      WHEN webid IS NULL AND appid is not null THEN 'App user'
      WHEN appid IS NULL AND webid is not null THEN 'Web user'
      ELSE 'Web and App user'
 END)
```

Comment: actually should have mentioned , the pic above the account id is not null, same as above Basically in the first line account id 1234 has web and app id both as seen in the first line and then account id 1234 in the second line is categorised as web user. However i would want the desired result of account id 1234 being categorised as web and app user